# How to convert the following map/list?

Tags: elixir

How to convert from `[[1, "A"], [2, "B"]]` to `[1: "A", 2: "B"]` in Elixir?

Have tried looking at pattern matching, comprehension, have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to have integers as a keys, it's better to use a map.
This code will return you map like `%{1 => "A", 2 => "B"}`.

```
a = [[1, "A"], [2, "B"]]
for [k, v] <- a, do: {k, v}, into: %{}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[1, "A"], [2, "B"]]
|> Enum.map(&List.to_tuple/1)
|> Enum.into(%{})
#⇒ %{1 => "A", 2 => "B"}
```

Please note, that `[1: "A", 2: "B"]` is not a legit structure in `Elixir`.

```
[[1, "A"], [2, "B"]]
|> Enum.map(&List.to_tuple/1)
|> Enum.into(Keyword.new)
#⇒ [{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}]
```

Despite how it’s output, it’s valid `Keyword` list:

```
Keyword.values [{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}]
#⇒ ["A", "B"]
Keyword.keys [{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}]
#⇒ [1, 2]
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a way to convert the string.

```
[[1, "A"], [2, "B"]] 
  |> Enum.map(fn [key, value] ->
    {String.to_atom(to_string(key)), value} end)
```

Thanks to https://github.com/JEG2

Comment: It's impossible to have `[1: "A", 2: "B"]`, since `:1` doesn't work in Elixir as an atom. In this example you can access from `a` keyword list your elements using `a[:"1"]`.

Comment: `String.to_atom(to_string(key))` might be changed to `:"#{key}"` to clarify the intent.